# How to disbale trailingSlash to false on single page in Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Hello i am new to NextJS, I am not getting how to disable trailingSlash disable only on single page of my nextjs application

Comment: Not possible out-of-the-box, but you could create a custom server to handle trailing slashes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't currently. You can only [set the behavior](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/trailing-slash) for all pages.